# Bootstrap columns aren't lining up

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout with 4 columns, 4x `col-md-3`. When I try to make the screen smaller, these columns have to behave to first 3 columns, then 2, and then 1 when the screen is too small.
But they don't, the columns just become smaller, and don't move beneath the other columns.
I must be missing something.

Code:

`<div class="row-fluid vakanties_strip_wrapper">
    <div ng-repeat="vakantie in vakanties">
      <a ui-sref="details_vakantie/({ vakantieId: vakantie.ID })">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <div class="vakantie_blok" ng-class="$even ? 'red' : 'blue'">
            <div class="vakantie_strip_img">
              SOME IMAGE
            </div>
            <div class="vakantie_strip_tekst_beschr">
              SOME TEXT
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>`

Comment: I'm quite sure the class `row-fluid` isn't part of Bootstrap. If you want it to be full width use `.container-fluid` with a regular `.row` inside it.

Comment: Actually @ckuijjer, it used to be in 2.3, but was phased out for `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this option.

```
<div class="row-fluid vakanties_strip_wrapper">
<div ng-repeat="vakantie in vakanties">
  <a ui-sref="details_vakantie/({ vakantieId: vakantie.ID })">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">   
      <div class="vakantie_blok" ng-class="$even ? 'red' : 'blue'">
        <div class="vakantie_strip_img">
          SOME IMAGE
        </div>
        <div class="vakantie_strip_tekst_beschr">
          SOME TEXT
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's better. I'm still surprised of the extra work that has to be done, if you compare BS3 to BS2, but the result is better. Thanks!